# document.createElement does not work as expected in componentDidMount in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, canvas, createelement

I am trying to create a canvas element on the fly, in order to execute `.toDataURL()` method after I've done some drawing. But the `document.createElement` does not have the expected behavior.

When I try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.width = 200;
    console.log(canvas);
}
```

I get in the console:

```
<canvas height="0" width="0"></canvas>
```

But using `componentDidUpdate` method works fine.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.width = 200;
    console.log(canvas);
}
```

```
<canvas height="100" width="200"></canvas>
```

What exactly is happening here ?

Please any answers concerning the right way in React using either `ref` or applying `<canvas />` element to DOM won't help me, as I am particularly trying to understand why there is this difference between `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in React.

Comment: You have to put your new HTML element (canvas) into the DOM. Where is it?

Comment: @cyntler I don't want in the DOM, I just want to use it on the fly, to finally execute the ```.toDataURL()``` method. Is it necessary to have it in the DOM ? Can't just use it on the fly ?

Comment: Okay, I see. It should works fine in my opinion. I made a small example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-sound-z3n0x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark using hook.

Comment: What is the problem? The code works

Comment: @cyntler Yeah, with hooks works, but what is going on with ```componentDidMount``` and ```componentDidUpdate``` ? Why it does not work in the first case but works on the second one ?

Answer (score 1):

[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is the proper way to target an element in React, and The proper way to creating an element in React returns them using jsx.

This example shows you how to make canvas:

```js
const App = () => {

  const drawCanvas = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.width = 200;
      ref.height = 100;
      const ctx = ref.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
    }
  };

  return <canvas ref={drawCanvas}/>
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```